# Changing base URL on part of a page only

Tags: php, html, url, symfony, relative-path

I have a page on my site that fetches and displays news items from the database of another (legacy) site on the same server. Some of the items contain **relative links** that should be fixed so that they **direct to the external site** instead of causing 404 errors on the main site.

I first considered using the `<base>` tag on the fetched news items, but this changes the base URL of the whole page, breaking the relative links in the main navigation - and it feels pretty hackish too.

I'm currently thinking of creating a regex to find the relative URLs (they all start with `/index.php?`) and prepending them with the desired base URL. Are there any more elegant solutions to this? The site is built on Symfony 2 and uses jQuery.

Comment: Does your new site not have an `/index.php` file? If not, why not just create one and put these lines in it: `header("{$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']} 301 Moved Permanently"); header('Location: http://othersite.tld/index.php?'.http_build_query($_GET));` - that way you don't have to modify the output on the new site at all. Also if you can't/don't want to do that, you say you are getting the data from the DB - are you getting the URLs as raw data, or getting pre-built HTML back?

Comment: @DaveRandom: Unfortunately the current site does have an `/index.php` and the data in the DB is pre-built HTML.

Comment: Well, at least you've made it challenging. How much HTML are we talking about? We all know the dangers of suggesting doing anything HTML/regex-related on SO (although in this case your looking for URLs and not looking at the HTML itself so it's probably alright) but if you can load it up into DOM and XPath for all elements with `src`/`href` attributes it would be better. Is it loads of small chunks, one big chunk or somewhere in between?

Comment: @DaveRandom: It's a couple thousand chunks of a few kilobytes each. Only one is displayed at a time but the lighter the better.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to just bulk-update the DB? This would be the best way. It could be done on the fly on every page load, but this adds precious milliseconds to the page load times...

Comment: @DaveRandom: I agree, but the problems don't end here - the legacy site is still in use and the link creator tool on the news publishing page creates relative links so new ones are added every week. We do have code base access, but since the legacy site is a steaming pile of spaghetti I'd prefer to steer clear of it for as long as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would tackle the problem:

```
function prepend_url ($prefix, $path) {
    // Prepend $prefix to $path if $path is not a full URL
    $parts = parse_url($path);
    return empty($parts['scheme']) ? rtrim($prefix, '/').'/'.ltrim($path, '/') : $path;
}

// The URL scheme and domain name of the other site
$otherDomain = 'http://othersite.tld';

// Create a DOM object
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->loadHTML($inHtml); // $inHtml is an HTML string obtained from the database

// Create an XPath object
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// Find candidate nodes
$nodesToInspect = $xpath->query('//*[@src or @href]');

// Loop candidate nodes and update attributes
foreach ($nodesToInspect as $node) {
    if ($node->hasAttribute('src')) {
        $node->setAttribute('src', prepend_url($otherDomain, $node->getAttribute('src')));
    }
    if ($node->hasAttribute('href')) {
        $node->setAttribute('href', prepend_url($otherDomain, $node->getAttribute('href')));
    }
}

// Find all nodes to export
$nodesToExport = $xpath->query('/html/body/*');

// Iterate and stringify them
$outHtml = '';
foreach ($nodesToExport as $node) {
    $outHtml .= $node->C14N();
}

// $outHtml now contains the "fixed" HTML as a string
```

[See it working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/MplrLP)

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much for this very thorough answer! We'll definitely do it this way. Much nicer than a quick and dirty regex solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can override the `base` tag by putting `http:\\` in front of the link.  That is, give a full url, not a relative URL.

Comment: True... not a nice solution though, is it? That means the new site has to use absolute paths for everything, which is arguably counter productive in the long run...

Comment: Not necessarily... I had a similar issue, and I just programmatically check the link, and if it does not already start with `http://` or `https://`, I add it to the start of the string.  It is only a few lines of code before adding the link.  Note, you could do this either with jQuery or PHH, but I use PHP.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, not actually a solution, but mostly a tip...

You could start playing aroung with [ExceptionController](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Controller/ExceptionController.php#L26).

There, **just for example**, you could seek for 404 error and check query string appended to request:

```
$request = $this->container->get('request');
....

if (404 === $exception->getStatusCode()) {
    $query = $request->server->get('QUERY_STRING');
    //...handle your logic
}
```

---

The other solution would be to define special route with its controller for such purposes, which would catch requests to `index.php` and do redirects and so on. Just define `index.php` in `requirements` of route and move this route on the top of your routing.

Not a clearest answer ever, but at least I hope I gave you a direction...

Cheers ;)