# PHP Regex to determine relative or absolute path

Tags: php, regex

I'm using cURL to pull the contents of a remote site. I need to check all "href=" attributes and determine if they're relative or absolute path, then get the value of the link and path it to something like href="http://www.website.com/index.php?url=[ABSOLUTE_PATH]"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I did something very similar to this recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759028/changing-base-url-on-part-of-a-page-only/11762303#11762303 - it's not exactly what you want but hopefully it will give you the general idea/a starting point

Comment: I'm not sure, but doesn't all absolute URLs start with a protocol, which in almost all cases is "http://"? So I guess you could just check whether the URL starts with that or not.

Comment: @DaveRandom - it seems to be working the only problem seems to be issues with html5 tags like 'header', 'footer', 'nav', etc... Any thoughts?

Comment: @Fluidbyte Can you show some sample HTML source you are trying to process?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the one possible solution if i understood question correctly:

```
$prefix = 'http://www.website.com/index.php?url=';
$regex = '~(<a.*?href\s*=\s*")(.*?)(".*?>)~is';
$html = file_get_contents('http://cnn.com');

$html = preg_replace_callback($regex, function($input) use ($prefix) {
  $parsed = parse_url($input[2]);

  if (is_array($parsed) && sizeof($parsed) == 1 && isset($parsed['path'])) {
    return $input[1] . $prefix . $parsed['path'] . $input[3];
  }
}, $html);

echo $html;
```

Answer (score 1):

A combination of a regex* and HTML's [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) should help:

```
// find all links in a page used within href="" or href='' syntax
$links = array();
preg_match_all('/href=(?:(?:"([^"]+)")|(?:\'([^\']+)\'))/i', $page_contents, $links);

// iterate through each array and check if it's "absolute"
$urls = array();
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $path = $link;
    if ((substr($link, 0, 7) == 'http://') || (substr($link, 0, 8) == 'https://')) {
        // the current link is an "absolute" URL - parse it to get just the path
        $parsed = parse_url($link);
        $path = $parsed['path'];
    }
    $urls[] = 'http://www.website.com/index.php?url=' . $path;
}
```

To determine if the URL is absolute or not, I simply have it check if the beginning of the URL is `http://` or `https://`; if your URLs contain other mediums such as `ftp://` or `tel:`, you might need to handle those as well.

This solution does use regex to parse HTML, which is often frowned upon. To circumvent, you could switch to using `[DOMDocument][2]`, but there's no need for extra code if there aren't any issues.