# PHP: How to get absolute link of href attribute

Tags: php

I'm trying to fetch favicon image path of a site and I'm doing something like:

```
$favicon_img_url = $link->getAttribute('href');
echo $favicon_img_url;
```

But it only returns the relative url (/favicon.ico) and NOT the absolute link (http://www.anysite.com/favicon.ico) that I want.

EDIT: For more clarity, here's a bigger chunk of the code:

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
    //Some code here to get contents from a website....
}

$html = file_get_contents_curl($target_website);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

// GET FAVICON PATH
$links = $doc->getElementsByTagName('link');
for ($i = 0; $i < $links->length; $i++)
{
$link = $links->item($i);
$rel = $link->getAttribute('rel');
if($rel == 'shortcut icon')
    $favicon = $link->getAttribute('href');
}
echo $favicon;
```

It only returns "/favicon.ico" not "http://www.website.com/favicon.ico"

Comment: what is this? are you using `DOMDocument`? show the complete codes

Comment: Does the href value have an absolute URL? if not, you could do:  
`$favicon_img_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $link->getAttribute('href');`

Comment: The site can be anything in random. Some use absolute path and some doesn't. What I want to get is the absolute path of the file regardless if the href attribute shows relative or absolute url.

Comment: @Ghost Yes, I use `DOMDocument`

Answer (score 0):

try add to relative path, domain url $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']

edit:
it give you domain without http or https. To add it, you can check if it is https or http: `if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])){..}else{...}`

Comment: The problem is, the site can be anything in random. Some use absolute path and some doesn't. If I add $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], will that cause any problem with absolute url? What I want to get is the absolute path of the file regardless if href attribute shows relative or absolute.

Comment: i see. I would check if received url is absolute or relative. If it is relative then i use above solution. How to check if url is relative/absolute? Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013268/php-regex-to-determine-relative-or-absolute-path

Answer (score 0):

The `href` attribute is defined as an (absolute/relative) path and stays that way. When the browser processes the HTML markup, it will do one of two things with that attribute:

- If it considers the attribute a valid absolute path, that will become that elements `href` property.
- If it considers the attribute a relative path, it will pop it on the end of the base URL and use that as the `href` property.

Take this page title for example, if you inspect the markup, the attribute is

> `/questions/26441184/php-how-to-get-absolute-link-of-href-attribute`

It is not an absolute path, but because the browser knows that the base URL is http://stackoverflow.com, clicking it will take you to the property value, which is:

> `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441184/php-how-to-get-absolute-link-of-href-attribute`

**tl;dr**: You can't, not without knowing the base URL for the page on which your `<a>` falls.